# Lightning Map(Lwc) is not working on playground and documentation demo

Tags: lightning-web-components

Lightning map demo from the LWC documentations is not working. I am getting the below error.

> Unable to resolve forcehelp/linkToNonSalesforceResource from
>   api/runtime/lwc-components/1.5.6-alpha/src/lightning/externalLink/externalLink.html

I am referring to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/example) link.
I checked it in the different browsers also, still no luck.

It's not even working when opened with the Playground.

[image]

Comment: I've asked about another issue that popped up over the weekend, I'll see if I can ask them about this one as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, It will be really helpful!

Comment: @sfdcfox any update?

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan No, I'll have to check back and see.

Comment: @sfdcfox do you have any update on this? Or should we use aura map for now?

Comment: @Novarg In salesforce org it should work just fine.. the issue is only with playground.